# Edwards Penney, Calculus: Early Transcendentals, 7th Ed., Ch 5.6 Ex 36: how is the integral in the solutions manual calculated?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, average

In the Calculus book "Calculus: Early Transcendentals" by Edwards and Penney, 7th Edition, in the chapter on the fundamental theorem of calculus, there is an exercise (Chapter 5.6, exercise 36) about the average value of a continuous function on a closed interval. The function is $$T(t)=80+10 \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{12}(t-10)\right)$$ and the average value is calculated on the interval [12, 18].

For me it was straightforward to calculate the average: $$\overline{T}=\frac{1}{18-12} \int_{12}^{18}T(t)dt$$

But my question is specifically about the calculation of the indefinite integral $$\int T(t)dt$$

My calculation is:

$$80t + 10\left(-\frac{12}{\pi}\cos {\frac{\pi}{12}(t-10)}\right)$$

The solution uses a different calculation, which I do not understand:

$$ \int T(t)dt = \frac{40}{\pi} \left( 2\pi(t-10)-3\cos {\frac{\pi(t-10)}{12}} \right) $$

**My question is how did they calculate the antiderivative in the line above?** Where does the $2\pi(t-10)$ com from for example?

Note that maple gives
$$ \int T(t)dt = 80t + \frac{120 \cos {\frac{1}{12}\pi t + \frac{1}{6} \pi}}{\pi}$$

which is also different, though when I graph $$\cos {\frac{1}{12}\pi t + \frac{1}{6} \pi}$$ I can see that it is the negative of $$\cos {\frac{\pi}{12}(t-10)},$$
so my calculation is the same as that of maple actually.

Comment: They might be different, but only by a constant.

Comment: They did a change of variable throughout; but note that your antiderivative and the one in the solution differ by $-80$, so the definite integral should come out the same.

Comment: Of course antiderivative of a function can differ by a constant, but my question is more "algebraically, what did the solutions manual do to get that particular form of the antiderivative"? It is not clear if it differs by a constant, and the way I did it seems like the textbook way to do it and they seem to have used some trick.

Comment: I think you're ascribing too much wisdom to the authors of solution manuals.  It could be they used a computer algebra system (not maple, I guess) and that's what came out.  As an instructor, your solution looks clear, and it's the method I would suggest other students use.

Comment: I believe that they did indeed use a change of variable to calculate the integral.

Comment: You integrated the $80$ separately, and then integrated the sine with a (possibly silent) change of variable, letting $u=\frac{\pi}{12}(t-10)$. What they did is do that change of variable on the whole integral, so that when they integrated $80$ they got $80u$, which then got changed to $80(\frac{\pi}{12}(t-10))$. Then they did a bit of arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments, you mention you want to know *how* the manual reached the solution they did. So here's what is most likely what happened.

You (possibly silently or in your head), essentially did the following:
$$\begin{align*}
\int \left(80+10 \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{12}(t-10)\right)\right)\,dt &= \int 80\,dt + \int 10\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{12}(t-10)\right)\,dt\\
&= 80t + 10\int\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{12}(t-10)\right)\,dt.
\end{align*}$$
You then make a change of variable, $u=\frac{\pi}{12}(t-10)$, $du = \frac{\pi}{12}\,dt$, so
$$\begin{align*}
\int\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{12}(t-10)\right)\,dt &= \int\frac{12}{\pi}\sin(u)\,du\\
&= -\frac{12}{\pi}\cos(u) + C\\
&= -\frac{12}{\pi}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{12}(t-10)\right)+C
\end{align*}$$
and putting it all together, you picked the antiderivative
$$F(t) = 80t +10\left(-\frac{12}{\pi}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{12}(t-10)\right)\right).$$

By contrast, they did the same change of variable, but they did it from the get-go:
$$\begin{align*}
\int \left(80+10 \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{12}(t-10)\right)\right)\,dt &=
\int\left( 80 + 10\left(\frac{12}{\pi}\sin(u)\right)\right)\,du\\
&= 80u + 10\left(-\frac{12}{\pi}\cos(u)\right) + C\\
&= 80\left(\frac{\pi}{12}(t-10)\right) \\
&\qquad\quad+ 10\left(-\frac{12}{\pi}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{12}(t-10)\right)\right) + C.
\end{align*}$$
Then they factor out a $\frac{40}{\pi}$ (note that $\gcd(80,120) = 40$; that's why they factor it out; and the $\pi$ denominator is to have that irrational denominator out in front), and choose the constant $C=0$ to get
$$\begin{align*}
80\left(\frac{\pi}{12}(t-10)\right) &+ 10\left(-\frac{12}{\pi}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{12}(t-10)\right)\right) \\
&= 
\frac{40}{\pi}\left( 2\pi(t-10) - 3\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{12}(t-10)\right)\right).
\end{align*}$$

Just between the two of us, yours is less complicated, more likely if you are doing it by hand.